# Will "0 A.D." Play in Lubuntu OS?

Tags: lubuntu, games

I'm a novice to computers and new to Lubuntu. I went to "apps.ubuntu.com" and it stated "0 A.D." has available versions for: Ubuntu 13.10 - 13.04 - 12.10 & 12.04

Lubuntu is not on the list. Does It matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have [the system requirements](http://play0ad.com/download/). Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. are the same operating system with different graphical interfaces and preinstalled programs.

Comment: +1, but to be annoyingly pedantic, Linux is the operating system and Ubuntu is the distribution. Good for Ubuntu doesn't necessarily imply good for Red Hat, say.

Comment: @Sparhawk, no. Linux is a kernel. By definition, the operating system provides the kernel and the user-space programs, therefore both views are correct: Linux distros are operating systems, and (most of them) are different distributions of the same GNU/Linux operating system (note that that is different from just Linux - GNU provides the basic user-space software).

Comment: @Sparhawk Your second sentence is not pertinent, because 1. 0AD system requirements (I'm thinking about the source code) do not include anything *Ubuntu-specific, and 2. we are not discussing a specific (dynamically-linked) binary (in which case, you would have had a point, because one of the main reasons for binary incompatibility between distributions is they have different `soname`s).

Comment: @Sparhawk 3. The differences between Ubuntu and other mainstream distros are far more deep than the differences between the *buntu's - I said "Good for Ubuntu almost always implies good for *buntu", which does not imply "Good for Ubuntu necessarily implies good for RH".

Comment: From you comments, I think I agree with you on most points. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding. You are correct that I should have said GNU/Linux instead of just Linux. However, my point was (I think) same as the last point you made. It'd be more specific to say *buntu are the same _distro_, hence (in general) software works across all. IMO this is more pertinent that saying it works on *buntu, hence works on all of the same _operating system_ (implying all GNU/Linux).

Comment: @Sparhawk I think you're missing the main point - "the same operating system" may or may not imply all GNU/Linux, depending on the context.